# How do I Change a UIViewController to a UITableViewController in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to swift/ios programming and following the hackingwithswift.org tutorials. I am to
specifically trying to `change the initial view controller to a table view`

The problem I am facing is I have no idea how to change the initial view controller to a table view. I tried copying the existing ViewController to a new `WebViewController` and update the existing swift file from:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
 ...
```

to :

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
 ...
```

with the required methods but when I run the simulator it crashes with :

```
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC" 
nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I think I need to update something in storyboard but I am lost as to what or how.

I am using xcode 12

This general workflow confuses me a lot and would also appreciate any links to doc/books to help someone whos a Fullstack developer with very little mobile exposure

Comment: Might be easier to just keep it as a `UIViewController`, and set the tableview delegates and datasource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in code you changed base class from `UIViewController` to `UITableViewController` then you have to drag a table template in IB not a usual VC

Comment: Thank you, it seems such a complicated thing to do but once it's spelled out it's really not